# Toggling between two chunks of markup with Knockout's fadeVisible?

Tags: knockout.js

I have two chunks of markup that I'm trying to toggle between by using the `fadeVisible` binding handler.  I can't seem to get smooth transitions happening in this scenario - meaning no jumpiness - is it possible?  Unfortunately, I can't use `position: absolute` or `fixed` as my container element needs to scale with the contents.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/8/

Code:

```
<!-- ko fadeVisible: show -->
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko fadeVisible: !show() -->
<div data-bind="text: 'Jones'"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: show" /> Show
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed the cant use position: absoulte thingamabob... but IF they are within a wrapper element surely they will be moveable like you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/10/
```

This should work.. Just wrap the div's in a container div and make the container relitive with the children fadeables being absolute

EDIT:
[New way that works](http://jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/46/)
Hi, looking through my old answers and thought I would have another go. Well I found a solution that works :) basically, don't use knockout for visual/dom manipulation, that's not it's primary role, instead use JQuery which does have dom manipulation as it's primary role.

This one will work without display types :)

Comment: also fyi, heres an example where I use absolute inside of a relitive container then have them positioned all over the place with no issues
http://jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/12/

Comment: Thanks for this, though this demonstrates why I can't use it: http://jsfiddle.net/xH3mh/13/  I don't know if it's possible :/

Comment: I enjoy a good problem solving exersize... but I got a wee bit annoyed that when I upped Knockout to 3.2 (you were running super duper old 2.1) it turns out they have removed onrender (or w/e it's called) from non foreeach stuff... so i couldn't see the final rendered text block (which i needed so i could mesure it's height to set the parents height)... If you can find a way to measure it's height then thats how its done.. but for now, maybe just extend your observable to include height and on the update of your binding modify the parents height to be correct.

Sorry I give up :P 3hrs later

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but I was reading through my old questions and found a better solution :)